# Strange Inkscape path behaviour - is this normal or a bug?

Tags: vector, inkscape, path

I'm trying to figure out if this is a bug I should report, or whether it's normal behaviour. (I don't think it is normal, but would appreciate others' thoughts)

I've created a simple triangle path on Inkscape, but when I drag handles to adjust a line's curves, nothing at all happens to the stroke of the shape - that's the black line in the image below. The red line shows the path's outline when I enable the '`Show path outline (without path effects)`' setting, which *does* reflect what I've been doing with the handles.

So, my question is.... is there any scenario in which this *should* happen in Inkscape? Or is it just being crackers?

[image: image shown on my screen]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've made your curves with the incredible Spiro Spline. It's a glorious tool that is worth reading about: http://www.levien.com/spiro/

To draw regular curves, switch the mode it the top toolbar.

To access spiro and other path filters, see Path > Path Effect Editor...

Comment: Yes, that was it! You're my hero.